# what is the best way to layout my checkboxes in javafx?

Tags: java, css, checkbox, javafx

[image]

I am trying to achieve this design using css and javafx and so far i think im on the right track, but where i am stuck at is the check boxes.I cant seem to get  them to layout correctly and functioning the way i want them to. I put 4 check Boxes in each of the two vboxs and put them both in the same cell to be able fit in one border that i set in the style sheet,but when i do this only the second column of check boxes work. I have tried other options such as using a second gridPane and laying out the check boxes in there then putting the second gridPane in the gridPane that i set for the scene, but that wouldn't even run so my question is  what is the best way to layout my check boxes so they look like this and are functioning properly? Here is what i have so far

```
 import javafx.scene.*;
 import javafx.stage.*;
 import javafx.geometry.*;
 import javafx.application.*;
 import javafx.scene.control.*;
 import javafx.scene.layout.*;
 import javafx.collections.*;
 import javafx.event.*;
 import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;

   public class ClassRegistrationForm extends Application{

    Scene scene1;

  Button createRequestButton,clearButton;

   Label peLabel,mathLabel,electivesLabel,englishLabel,spaceLabel;

   RadioButton english12,english11,english10,english9;
   ToggleGroup group;

 ComboBox<String>electivesComboBox;

 CheckBox healthBox,sportsBox,liftingBox,aerobicsBox,
 archeryBox,swimmingBox,yogaBox,bowlingBox;

    HBox buttonHbox;
    VBox englishVbox,mathVbox,electivesVbox,peVbox1,peVbox2;

    GridPane peClassesGridPane;

     ListView<String> mathClassesListView;
     ObservableList<String> mathClassesList;


public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Class Registration Application");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();




        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        peClassesGridPane = new GridPane();
        scene1 = new Scene(gridPane);






       buttonHbox = new HBox();

       createRequestButton = new Button("Create Request");
       clearButton = new Button("Clear");
       buttonHbox.getChildren().addAll(createRequestButton,clearButton);
       gridPane.setConstraints(buttonHbox,0,2);


       peLabel = new Label("Pe"); 
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(peLabel,0,0);
       healthBox = new CheckBox("Health");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(healthBox,0,1);
       yogaBox = new CheckBox("Yoga");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(yogaBox,0,2);
       sportsBox = new CheckBox("Sports");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(sportsBox,0,3);
       archeryBox = new CheckBox("Archery");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(archeryBox,0,4);

       spaceLabel = new Label("");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(spaceLabel,1,0);
       liftingBox = new CheckBox("Lift");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(liftingBox,1,1);
       swimmingBox = new CheckBox("Swim");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(swimmingBox,1,2);
       aerobicsBox = new CheckBox("Aero");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(aerobicsBox,1,3);
       bowlingBox = new CheckBox("Bowl");
       peClassesGridPane.setConstraints(bowlingBox,1,4);
       peClassesGridPane.getChildren().addAll(
       peLabel,healthBox,yogaBox,sportsBox,archeryBox,spaceLabel,
        liftingBox,swimmingBox,aerobicsBox,bowlingBox
       );  

       gridPane.setConstraints(peClassesGridPane,0,1);



       mathVbox = new VBox();
       mathVbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       mathVbox.setPrefSize(150,100);
       mathClassesListView = new ListView();
      mathClassesListView.setPrefSize(100,50);
       mathClassesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Algebra 1-2",
                "Algebra 3-4",
                "Geometry",
                "Pre-Calculus",
                "Calculus"
         );
        mathClassesListView.setItems(mathClassesList);



       mathLabel = new Label("Math Classes");
       mathVbox.getChildren().addAll(mathLabel,mathClassesListView);
       gridPane.setConstraints(mathVbox,1,1);




       englishVbox = new VBox();
      englishVbox.setPrefSize(200, 200);
       englishVbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
       group  = new ToggleGroup();

    englishLabel = new Label("English Classes");
        englishVbox.getChildren().add(englishLabel);
    english12 = new RadioButton("English12");
    english12.setToggleGroup(group);
        englishVbox.getChildren().add(english12);
    english11 = new RadioButton("English11");
    english11.setToggleGroup(group);
        englishVbox.getChildren().add(english11);
    english10 = new RadioButton("English12");
    english10.setToggleGroup(group);
    englishVbox.getChildren().add(english10);
    english9 = new RadioButton("English9");
        english9.setToggleGroup(group);
    englishVbox.getChildren().add(english9);
    gridPane.setConstraints(englishVbox,0,0);

        electivesVbox = new VBox();
        electivesVbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    electivesLabel = new Label("Electives");


    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Java"
            , "Web Design"
            , "Welding"
            , "Woods"
            , "Art"
            , "Band"
            , "GameDesign"
            , "Graphic Arts");
    electivesComboBox = new ComboBox<String>();
    electivesComboBox.setItems(data);

           electivesVbox.getChildren().addAll(
  electivesLabel,electivesComboBox
 );

       gridPane.setConstraints(electivesVbox,0,1);   



          gridPane.getChildren().addAll(
  englishVbox,electivesVbox,peVbox1,peVbox2,mathVbox,
  buttonHbox,peClassesGridPane
 );

    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.show();
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

  }




   }
```

Comment: A GridPane is the best way to lay those out.

Comment: @James_D i have tried doing that but it didnt compile.....i guess ill just try that out again and post the code

Comment: @James_D i have tried your solution but the result....wouldn't compile maybe you can post a working example?

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me. You get a `NullPointerException` though because you never initialize `peClassesGridPane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize `peClassesGridPane`. Just add in the line

`peClassesGridPane = new GridPane();`

before you use it. Additionally, remove the redundant `peVBox1` and `peVBox2` from the code entirely.